# PyDev: Undefined variable from import: __name__

Tags: eclipse, import, pydev, importerror

I use regularly the `__name__` property of classes in my code (which works perfectly in Python) but **PyDev** is always marking it as an error (**Undefined variable from import**).

I tried to add the `__name__` to the bulletin imports but this did not remove the problem.

When I use auto completion, PyDev finds a `__class__` property when typing a `.` behind a class which is wrong. But if I use `__class__` property anyway, PyDev finds the `__name__` property.

Is there any bug in PyDev that has to do with mixing up classes with instanced objects?
Is there any workaround?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in PyDev. Please report that in the PyDev sf tracker. See: http://pydev.org/about.html for links.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem. After reading some forms on it, it looks like it's a problem with the console or kernel not loading fast-enough...

I just closed the document and re-opened it and all the errors went away.