# Undefined variable from import PyGame_SDL2 in PyDev?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm creating an android game in PyDev using pygame_sdl2 and RAPT, but I keep getting these errors on specific lines of code:

```
#                                                  V here V
elif ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_AC_BACK:
```

which gives me:

```
Undefined variable from import: K_AC_BACK
```

I'm wondering if this is a pygame error or a PyDev error; some people seem to be having similar problems with PyDev itself (like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831854/pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-name)) but I tried those and nothing happens.

Could anyone please give me some direction on how to fix this?

Comment: check PyGame_SLD2 source code  on github. I don't see `K_AC_BACK` in in file [locale.pyx](https://github.com/renpy/pygame_sdl2/blob/master/src/pygame_sdl2/locals.pyx). But maybe `sdl2.SDLK_AC_BACK`  will work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! And I was using [this](https://github.com/renpytom/rapt-pygame-example/blob/master/main.py) as a reference. It seems to be by the creator itself.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of Pygame at the time of writing, the problem is not reproducible. The following minimal example runs without any problems:

```py
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_AC_BACK:
            print('K_AC_BACK')

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```